# How to remove copy option from shared folders?

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing

My organisation uses **WS2012** and want to **share** some **files** over the network. My question is how to **copy protect a folder/file** which is being shared?

The scenario is that, I want the users to access the folders but not to copy, delete or paste anything from or on it.

Please suggest how to achieve that, any help is appreciated.

P.S : I do not prefer using any third-party tool on a server, although heard of doing it through `regedit` but I do no know much about the registry keys, so a little guidance is needed.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share something with your users, by definition you are making it available to them to read/view and copy.

Preventing delete and editing files is easy, just use Read permissions exclusively on the share or the files.

But the user will be able to copy the content of the shared files. If you want to prevent that, you have to lock down the user's workstation to prevent that the data is leaving that PC. Disallow an USB devices and removable disks, and prevent any other network access especially to the public internet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read Active Directory Rights Management Services at this link [AD RMS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771627.aspx)